# threads and locks

Tags: multithreading

I do not not know anything about multithreading programming so wanted to post a general question here. How can I do the following:

main()
 run MyMethod every 30 seconds

MyMethod()
   1. get data
   2. do calculations
   3. save result into file

How can I make sure that I finish saving results (MyMethod step 3) before main start running MyMethod again ? Basically I have to lock that thread somehow until MyMethod is done. Feel free to use any language as example I'm more interested in the concept how such things are done in reality.

Thanks

Comment: Does main() have to do anything except start the thread once?  Can the thread not just mark the start time, perform 123, mark end time, calculate intervalMs=end-start, if (30000-intervalMs) not negative, sleep(30000-intervalMs), loop back round?  Autonomous operation, no locks, no synchronization, no main thread actions required after starting thread, zero chance of starting multiple threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need synchronization. You only need to make sure that the thread work is completed, since saving happens at the end.

```
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>


int MyMethod(){
    // some code
}

int run(){
    std::thread thrd(MyMethod);
    sleep(30);
    thrd.join();
}

int main(){
    while(true)
        run();  
}
```

Comment: Please note that this code is pragmatically the same as if the main thread did the work by itself.